OSError: [Errno 110] ETIMEDOUT
I am trying to use a DHT11 sensor with 3 pins from my elegoo kit. I have followed the data sheet and connected the 3 pins correctly but each time I try and run different codes, I get this error: OSError: [Errno 110] ETIMEDOUT. I cant seem to figure out the problem I am encountering. I am using a w5100s-evb-pico with micropython. If anyone can help me figure out this issue it would be much appriciated. I will show some codes I have used as examples.
Code 1:
from machine import Pin
import utime as time
from dht import DHT11

dataPin=16

myPin= Pin(dataPin,Pin.OUT,Pin.PULL_DOWN)
sensor=DHT11(myPin)

while True:
    sensor.measure()
    tempC=sensor.temperature()
    hum=sensor.humidity()
    print(tempC,hum)
    time.sleep(1)

Code 2:
import machine
import dht
import time

sensor = dht.DHT11(machine.Pin(16))

while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(2)
        sensor.measure()
        temp = sensor.temperature() # eg. 23 (°C)
        hum = sensor.humidity()    # eg. 41 (% RH)
        print('Temperature: %3.1f C' %temp)
        print('Humidity: %3.1f %%' %hum)
    except OSError as e:
        print('Failed to read sensor.')

I've tried using different codes, watched different videos, rewired but nothing has solved my issue.

ETIMEDOUT most likely means that the DHT11 isn't found.
You might want to check the cables and your DHT11. If you have another device, check with it.

Ok I ordered another DHT11 sensor and it comes tomorrow so I will check out if that one works.

This happened to me as well using a DHT11 (blue) but with a NodeMCU, not a Pi Pico. Oddly enough defining the sensor as a DHT22 first, measuring, then redefining as DHT11 got it to work.
import dht
import machine

d = dht.DHT11(machine.Pin(2))
d.measure()

>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
>>>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>>>   File "dht.py", line 1, in measure
>>> OSError: [Errno 110] ETIMEDOUT

What worked for me.
import dht
import machine

d = dht.DHT22(machine.Pin(2))
d.measure()
d = dht.DHT11(machine.Pin(2))
d.measure()
d.temperature()

>>> 30

d.humidity()

>>> 32

